# Haskell - Calculating the shortest path using trees

Tags: haskell, graph, path-finding

i am trying to write a code in haskell, that goes from point A, to point F, on a board game, that is essentially a Matrix, following the shortest path.

This is the board:

```
AAAA
ACCB
ADEF
*
0 0 N
```

The robot enters on the letter A, on the bottom (where it is the * ), and must reach F, on the bottom of the board are the coordinates, x=0, y=0, and pointing towards North. F coordinate is (3,0)

The trick is, it can't jump more than one letter, it can go from A to B, B to C, etc. and it can walk through the letters of the type (A to A, B to B, etc)

It can only move forward and make turns (Left, right) so the path to let me go to F would be

Forward, Forward, Right, Forward ,Forward, Forward, Right, Jump, Right, Jump, Forward, Left, Jump, Left, Forward, Forward

Once it reaches F, it's done.

I want to try this approach, using a Tree

```
                  A
                 / \
                A   D
               / \ 
              /   \
             A     C
            / \   / \
           /   \ D   C
          A     
         / \  
        /   \ 
       A
      /
     /
    A
   / \
  B   A
 / \  
C   F
```

After that i would only need to validate the correct path and shortest right?

Problem is , i don't have that much experience using trees.

Would you indicate any other way to get the best path?

Thank you very much .

Comment: A tree for this problem will have either 2 or 3 branches - 2 if the only legal moves are `Left` and `Right` and 3 if there's also a legal move forward - either `Forward` or `Jump`. Finding the shortest path (if turning `Left` or `Right` counts as a move) is then finding `F` at the smallest depth in the tree. If turning `Left` and `Right` don't count as a move, the tree will have 0-3 or 0-4 branches depending on which directions have legal moves and whether you prune (disallow) moving backwards.

Comment: While you will eventually traverse through a tree of states, you don't need to actually build such a tree in memory: you only care about finding the shortest path, so all you have to do is to start from the initial game state and propagate the game one step at a time, trying all possible combinations *simultaneously*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We're going to solve this problem by searching a tree in three parts. First we will build a `Tree` representing the paths through the problem, with branches for each state. We'd like to find the shortest path to get to a state with a certain criteria, so we will write a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) for searching any `Tree`. This won't be fast enough for the example problem you provided, so we will improve on the breadth first search with a [transposition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_table) which keeps track of states we have already explored to avoid exploring them again.

#### Building a Tree

We'll assume that your playing board is represented in an [`Array` from `Data.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html)

```
import Data.Array

type Board = Array (Int, Int) Char

board :: Board
board = listArray ((1,1),(3,4)) ("AAAA" ++ "ACCB" ++ "ADEF")
```

`Data.Array` doesn't provide a default easy way to make sure indexes that we look up values for with `!` are actually in the bounds of the `Array`. For convenience, we'll provide a safe version that returns `Just v` if the value is in the `Array` or `Nothing` otherwise.

```
import Data.Maybe

(!?) :: Ix i => Array i a -> i -> Maybe a
a !? i = if inRange (bounds a) i then Just (a ! i) else Nothing
```

The `State` of the puzzle can be represented by the combination of a `position` of the robot and the `direction` that the robot is facing.

```
data State = State {position :: (Int, Int), direction  :: (Int, Int)}
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

The `direction` is a unit vector that can be added to the `position` to get a new `position`. We can rotate the direction vector `left` or `right` and `moveTowards` it.

```
right :: Num a => (a, a) -> (a, a)
right (down, across) = (across, -down)

left ::  Num a => (a, a) -> (a, a)
left (down, across) = (-across, down)

moveTowards :: (Num a, Num b) => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> (a, b)
moveTowards (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
```

To explore a board, we will need to be able to determine from a state what moves are legal. To do this it'd be useful to name the moves, so we'll make a data type to represent the possible moves.

```
import Prelude hiding (Right, Left)

data Move = Left | Right | Forward | Jump
    deriving (Show)
```

To determine what moves are legal on a board we need to know which `Board` we are using and the `State` of the robot. This suggests the type `moves :: Board -> State -> Move`, but we re going to be computing the new state after each move just to decide if the move was legal, so we will also return the new state for convenience.

```
moves :: Board -> State -> [(Move, State)]
moves board (State pos dir) =   
    (if inRange (bounds board) pos then [(Right,   State pos    (right dir)), (Left, State pos (left dir))] else []) ++
    (if next == Just here          then [(Forward, State nextPos dir)] else []) ++
    (if next == Just (succ here)   then [(Jump,    State nextPos dir)] else [])
    where
        here = fromMaybe 'A' (board !? pos)
        nextPos = moveTowards dir pos
        next = board !? nextPos
```

If we're on the board, we can turn `Left` and `Right`; the restriction that we be on the board guarantees all the `State`s returned by `moves` have `position`s that are on the board. If the value held at the `nextPos`, `next` position matches what is `Just here` we can go `Forward` to it (if we're off the board, we assume what is `here` is `'A'`). If `next` is `Just` the successor of what is `here` we can `Jump` to it. If `next` is off the board it is `Nothing` and can't match either `Just here` or `Just (succ here)`.

Up until this point, we've just provided the description of the problem and haven't touched on answering the question with tree. We are going to use the rose tree `Tree` defined in [`Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.2/docs/Data-Tree.html).

```
data Tree a = Node {
        rootLabel :: a,         -- ^ label value
        subForest :: Forest a   -- ^ zero or more child trees
    }

type Forest a = [Tree a]
```

Each node of a `Tree a` holds a single value `a` and a list of branches which are each a `Tree a`.

We are going to build a list of `Tree`s in a straightforward manner from our `moves` function. We are going to make each result of `moves` the `rootLabel` of a `Node` and make the branches be the list of `Tree`s we get when we `explore` the new state.

```
import Data.Tree

explore :: Board -> State -> [Tree (Move, State)]
explore board = map go . moves board
    where
        go (label, state) = Node (label, state) (explore board state)
```

At this point, our trees are infinite; nothing keeps the robot from endlessly spinning in place.. We can't draw one, but we could if we could `limit` the tree to just a few steps.

```
limit :: Int -> Tree a -> Tree a
limit n (Node a ts)
    | n <= 0    = Node a []
    | otherwise = Node a (map (limit (n-1)) ts)
```

We'll display just the first couple levels of the tree when we start off the bottom left corner facing towards the board in `State (4, 1) (-1, 0)`.

```
(putStrLn .
 drawForest .
 map (fmap (\(m, s) -> show (m, board ! position s)) . limit 2) .
 explore board $ State (4, 1) (-1, 0))

(Forward,'A')
|
+- (Right,'A')
|  |
|  +- (Right,'A')
|  |
|  `- (Left,'A')
|
+- (Left,'A')
|  |
|  +- (Right,'A')
|  |
|  `- (Left,'A')
|
`- (Forward,'A')
   |
   +- (Right,'A')
   |
   +- (Left,'A')
   |
   `- (Forward,'A')
```

#### Breadth First Search

Breadth first search explores all the possibilities at one level (across the "breadth" of what is being searched) before descending into the next level (into the "depth" of what is being searched). Breadth first search finds the shortest path to a goal. For our trees, this means exploring everything at one layer before exploring any of what's in the inner layers. We'll accomplish this by making a queue of nodes to explore adding the nodes we discover in the next layer to the end of the queue. The queue will always hold nodes from the current layer followed by nodes from the next layer. It will never hold any nodes from the layer past that because we won't discover those nodes until we have moved on to the next layer.

To implement that, we need an efficient queue, so we'll use a [sequence from Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.2/docs/Data-Sequence.html)/

```
import Data.Sequence (viewl, ViewL (..), (><))
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
```

We start with an empty queue `Seq.empty` of nodes to explore and an empty path `[]` into the `Tree`s. We add the initial possibilities to the end of the `queue` with `><` (concatenation of sequences) and `go`. We look at the start of the `queue`. If there's nothing left, `EmptyL`, we didn't find a path to the goal and return `Nothing`. If there is something there, and it matches the goal `p`, we return the path we have accumulate backwards. If the first thing in the queue doesn't match the goal we add it as the most recent part of the path and add all of its branches to the remainder of what was `queued`.

```
breadthFirstSearch :: (a -> Bool) -> [Tree a] -> Maybe [a]
breadthFirstSearch p = combine Seq.empty []
    where
        combine queue ancestors branches =
            go (queue >< (Seq.fromList . map ((,) ancestors) $ branches))
        go queue =
            case viewl queue of
                EmptyL -> Nothing
                (ancestors, Node a bs) :< queued ->
                    if p a
                    then Just . reverse $ a:ancestors
                    else combine queued (a:ancestors) bs
```

This lets us write our first `solve` for `Board`s. It's convenient here that all of the positions returned from `moves` are on the board.

```
solve :: Char -> Board -> State -> Maybe [Move]
solve goal board = fmap (map fst) . breadthFirstSearch ((== goal) . (board !) . position . snd) . explore board
```

If we run this for our board it never finishes! Well, eventually it will, but my back of a napkin calculation suggests it will take about 40 million steps. The path to the end of the maze is 16 steps long and the robot is frequently presented with 3 options for what to do at each step.

```
> solve 'F' board (State (4, 1) (-1, 0))
```

We can solve much smaller puzzles like

```
AB
AC
*
```

Which we can represent the board for this puzzle with

```
smallBoard :: Board
smallBoard = listArray ((1,1),(2,2)) ("AB" ++ "AC")
```

We `solve` it looking for `'C'` starting in row `3` column `1` looking towards lower numbered rows.

```
> solve 'C' smallBoard (State (3, 1) (-1, 0))
Just [Forward,Forward,Right,Jump,Right,Jump]
```

#### Transposition Table

Certainly this problem must be easier to solve than exploring 40 million possible paths. Most of those paths consist of spinning in place or randomly meandering back and forth. The degenerate paths all share one property, they keep visiting states they have already visited. In the `breadthFirstSeach` code, those paths keep adding the same nodes to the queue. We can get rid of all of this extra work just by remembering the nodes that we've already seen.

We'll remember the set of nodes we've already seen with a [`Set` from `Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.2/docs/Data-Set.html).

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
```

To the signature of `breadthFirstSearch` we'll add a function from the label for a node to a representation for the branches of that node. The representation should be equal whenever all the branches out of the node are the same. In order to quickly compare the representations in `O(log n)` time with a `Set` we require that the representation have an `Ord` instance instead of just equality. The `Ord` instance allows `Set` to check for membership with [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

```
breadthFirstSearchUnseen:: Ord r => (a -> r) -> (a -> Bool) -> [Tree a] -> Maybe [a]
```

In addition to keeping track of the `queue`, `breadthFirstSearchUnseen` keeps track of the set of representations that have been `seen`, starting with `Set.empty`. Each time we add branches to the `queue` with `combine` we also add the representations to `seen`. We only add the `unseen` branches whose representations are not in the set of branches we've already `seen`.

```
breadthFirstSearchUnseen repr p = combine Set.empty Seq.empty []
    where
        combine seen queued ancestors unseen =
            go
                (seen  `Set.union` (Set.fromList . map (repr . rootLabel) $ unseen))
                (queued ><         (Seq.fromList . map ((,) ancestors   ) $ unseen))
        go seen queue =
            case viewl queue of
                EmptyL -> Nothing
                (ancestors, Node a bs) :< queued ->
                    if p a
                    then Just . reverse $ ancestors'
                    else combine seen queued ancestors' unseen
                    where
                        ancestors' = a:ancestors
                        unseen = filter (flip Set.notMember seen . repr . rootLabel) bs
```

Now we can improve our `solve` function to use `breadthFirstSearchUnseen`. All of the branches from a node are determined by the `State` - the `Move` label that got to that state is irrelevant - so we only use the `snd` part of the `(Move, State)` tuple as the representation for a node.

```
solve :: Char -> Board -> State -> Maybe [Move]
solve goal board = fmap (map fst) . breadthFirstSearchUnseen snd ((== goal) . (board !) . position . snd) . explore board
```

We can now `solve` the original puzzle very quickly.

```
> solve 'F' board (State (4, 1) (-1, 0))
Just [Forward,Forward,Forward,Right,Forward,Forward,Forward,Right,Jump,Right,Jump,Forward,Left,Jump,Left,Jump,Jump]
```

Comment: Cirdec, i can't thank you enough! I will go thoroughly the code, and if i have any doubts, i will count on you to help me. I can't thank you enough, seriously.

Comment: One more thing, i think that when importing Data.Tree , it should go as : `import qualified Data.Tree as Tree` Otherwise, it will generate ambiguous occurrence.